# How would I write a linear search of an arraylist of a custom class?

Tags: java, for-loop, javafx, arraylist, reference

I've got a for loop, which runs through each element in the `ArrayList`, and if it matches the value of the `String`, I need it to ammend a parameter of a variable that has the same name. Is that even possible? It's the bit that goes `ref.setPickOnBounds(false);` I've tried to provide an altered minimum reproducible example (I do need to alter a `boolean` parameter, but not this one, for example). Does anyone know if it is possible?:

```
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;

public class Example extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ArrayList<String> someArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        someArray.add("triangle");
        someArray.add("circle");
        someArray.add("square");

        Polygon triangle = new Polygon(50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50);
        triangle.setPickOnBounds(false);

        TextField bText = new TextField();
        bText.setMaxWidth(200);

        Button button1 = new Button();

        root.getChildren().addAll(triangle);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 350);


        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("My Example");
        stage.show();


        button1.setOnAction(e -> {
            for (int i = 0; i <= someArray.size(); i++) {
                if (someArray.get(i).equals(BText.getText().toLowerCase())) {
                    String ref = bText.get(i);
                    ref.setPickOnBounds(false);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you lay your code out using proper indentation, so that it's readable? Any IDE will have the functionality to do that, and then you can just copy and paste it here.

Comment: Anyway, no; there's no direct way to do that. I don't even believe that local variable names are guaranteed to be retained at runtime. Either put the shapes in a map, referenced by the name, or create a class that encapsulates the shape and its name. (Also: note that your `for` loop as written is guaranteed to throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.)

Comment: Ok thanks @James_D, I have some limitations as to what I can use at the moment, so I'm going to try and implement an array of custom class objects, and use a nested loop to access the boolean value. I just need to look up the syntax as I know it's different to an array. Thanks again (apologies for the formatting).

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. Just create a simple class (or record) encapsulating a shape and a name for the shape. Put the instances in a list. Iterate through the list and compare the text from the text field to each name. If it matches, get the shape and do whatever you need to do with it. You don't need a nested loop. You don't need "special syntax". It's just plain, basic Java, nothing else.